# asp.net mvc passing IEnumerable<model> from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, controls

i have a IEnumerable model that after population will display in a VIEW in a table for confirmation an then user clicks on import button to complete the import process so i need to call import action method to do that and also i need to pass the model to that import action method as parameter .... (note that my model is not a DB model...just a simple class).....this is my model

```
public class Dairy_XL
    {
        public int No { get; set; }
        public string RegNo { get; set; }
        public string NAAB_CODE { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string ICC { get; set; }
        public string LNM { get; set; }
        public string LFM { get; set; }
        public string MILK { get; set; }
        public string FAT { get; set; }
        public string PRO { get; set; }
        public string SCE { get; set; }
        public string PL { get; set; }
        public string DPR { get; set; }
        public string PTAT { get; set; }
        public string UDC { get; set; }
        public string FLC { get; set; }
        public string TPI { get; set; }
        public string SIRE { get; set; }
        public string MGS { get; set; }
        public string FEE { get; set; }
        public string CAP { get; set; }
        public string X_FLAG { get; set; }
        public string STAT { get; set; }
        public int ACTION_FLAG { get; set; } 

        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        public bool color_reg { get; set; }
        public bool color_naab { get; set; }
        public bool color_name { get; set; }
        public bool color_icc { get; set; }
        public bool color_lnm { get; set; }
        public bool color_lfm { get; set; }
        public bool color_milk { get; set; }
        public bool color_fat { get; set; }
        public bool color_pro { get; set; }
        public bool color_sce { get; set; }
        public bool color_pl { get; set; }
        public bool color_dpr { get; set; }
        public bool color_ptat { get; set; }
        public bool color_udc { get; set; }
        public bool color_flc { get; set; }
        public bool color_tpi { get; set; }
        public bool color_fee { get; set; }
        public bool color_cap { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and this is my confirmation VIEW which i try to call a action method using a action link and passing the model(last lines)

```
@model IEnumerable<Javad_New.Models.Dairy_XL>
.......    
<div class="container-fluid" style="overflow-x: auto; margin-top: 50px">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: darkcyan; color: white">
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>RegNO</th>
                    <th>NAAB CODE</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>ICC</th>
                    <th>LNM</th>
                    <th>LFM</th>
                    <th>MILK</th>
                    <th>FAT</th>
                    <th>PRO</th>
                    <th>SCE</th>
                    <th>PL</th>
                    <th>DPR</th>
                    <th>PTAT</th>
                    <th>UDC</th>
                    <th>FLC</th>
                    <th>TPI</th>
                    <th>SIRE</th>
                    <th>MGS</th>
                    <th>FEE</th>
                    <th>موجودی</th>
                    <th>X-FLAG</th>
                    <th>STAT</th>

                </tr>


            </thead>

            <tbody id="mytbody3">

             @foreach (var d in Model)
             {
                <tr>

                    <td>@d.No</td>

                    @if (d.color_reg)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.RegNo)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.RegNo)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_naab)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.NAAB_CODE)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.NAAB_CODE)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_name)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.NAME)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.NAME)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_icc)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.ICC)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.ICC)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_lnm)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.LNM)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.LNM)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_lfm)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.LFM)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.LFM)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_milk)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.MILK)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.MILK)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_fat)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.FAT)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.FAT)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_pro)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.PRO)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.PRO)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_sce)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.SCE)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.SCE)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_pl)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.PL)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.PL)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_dpr)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.DPR)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.DPR)</td>
                    }

                    @if (d.color_ptat)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.PTAT)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.PTAT)</td>
                    }
                    @if (d.color_udc)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.UDC)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.UDC)</td>
                    }
                    @if (d.color_flc)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.FLC)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.FLC)</td>
                    }
                    @if (d.color_tpi)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.TPI)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.TPI)</td>
                    }

                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.SIRE)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.MGS)</td>

                    @if (d.color_fee)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.FEE)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.FEE)</td>
                    }
                    @if (d.color_cap)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:lightcoral">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.CAP)</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.CAP)</td>
                    }

                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => d.X_FLAG)</td>

                    @if (d.ACTION_FLAG == 1)
                    {
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;background-color:lightcoral">@Html.Raw(d.STAT)</td>
                    }
                    else if (d.ACTION_FLAG == 2)
                    {

                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;background-color:lightskyblue">@Html.Raw(d.STAT)</td>
                    }
                    else if (d.ACTION_FLAG == 3)
                    {
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;background-color:lightgreen">@Html.Raw(d.STAT)</td>
                    }

                </tr>
              }                   


            </tbody>


        </table>


    </div>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.ActionLink("IMPORT", "Import_Dairy_XL", new { xl_model = Model })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
    </div>
```

but after i count the list inside the import action it displays 0.

```
 public ActionResult Import_Dairy_XL(List<Dairy_XL> xl_model)
        {

            //Dairy_XL dairy_xl_model = new Dairy_XL();

            //ViewBag.test = xl_model.Where(x => x.RegNo == "123").Select(y => y.RegNo).SingleOrDefault();
            ViewBag.test = xl_model.Count;



            return View();
        }
```

Comment: If you look at the `href` attribute of the link your generating you will understand why this does not work. But the idea of posting back a collection of objects to the server when the server already knows it is just crazy. Just post back some ID that identifies you collection and then get it again in the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Passing entire collection as action method argument with `ActionLink` that uses `HttpGet` method makes no sense since collection items will transformed as query string in URL and potentially exceeding its limit. Just use ID property of that collection (usually an `int` property) as parameter like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("IMPORT", "Import_Dairy_XL", "ControllerName", new { no = d.No })
```

The `ActionLink` given above should be placed into `foreach` loop of view page containing collection items.

Then, pass designated ID property as action method parameter, given in this example:

```
// somewhere in controller declaration
List<Dairy_XL> list = new List<Dairy_XL>() { new Dairy_XL() { ... }, ... };

// action method part
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Import_Dairy_XL(int no)
{
    // use LINQ to query that list with passed value from property
    Dairy_XL model = list.Where(x => x.No == no).SingleOrDefault();

    // other logic

    // put something to pass into view
    return View(model);
}
```

Afterwards, you can create another view which displays query result:

```
@model Javad_New.Models.Dairy_XL

@* ID property as example *@
<p>@Model.No</p>

<!-- other properties -->
```

You can see a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464343/passing-model-in-collection-to-actionlink).

Comment: thank you for response..... actually my logic is some thing like this  start -> get data from excel and populate the model -> shows the view of model for **confirmation** -> if OK click on actionlink or button to insert all values to db -->clear model for next.... thats why i need to pass all records as arg